# OpenshiftOnline - an application from the DockerHub image

Tags: java, openshift

I wonder how these images on Openshift Online are replaced if there is a newer version in DockerHub? It is known that you can throw the application away and add it from the beginning but there is probably a faster way, e.g. something that will update Image Stream and then do a new image deploy?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a so-called "image change trigger", by using an `ImageStream`. You can find a quick overview of how this can be set up here: https://okd-docs.cloud.duke.edu/user-guide/triggerFromDockerhub/

```
# Set up ImageStream
oc import-image docker.io/library/centos:centos7 --confirm --scheduled=true

# Set an image change trigger on your existing DeploymentConfig
oc set triggers dc myapp --from-image=docker.io/library/centos:centos7 --containers=mycontainer
```